# Stripe documentation style sidenav with react

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, sidebar, user-experience

Does anyone have any ideas how I can achieve the sidenav on the stripe documentation page https://stripe.com/docs The side nav has nested elements. I was wondering how on click of "Payments" on the home page can I open up the payments side nav and its nested list and do a redirect to the payments page. I know that doesn't make sense but if you click the docs page and try you may understand what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve similar behavior with CSS height transition. They appears to be pretty smooth on desktop (60fps is achievable but not through full transition period). If you need more control (for example close other navigation 'ul's when other is opened) you can remove checkbox elements and change label elements to "h2". Then set "onclick" listener on "h2" elements in JS code that will add class (with styles from "input:checked ~ ul") to selected "ul".

```css
:root {
  --liHeight: 1em
}

label {
  cursor: pointer
}

ul {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

ul li {
  height: var(--liHeight);
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

input:checked ~ ul {
  opacity: 1;
  position: initial;
  height: calc(7 * var(--liHeight));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="item">
    <label for="item1">
      Item 1
    </label>
    <input id="item1" type="checkbox"/>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <label for="item2">
      Item 2
    </label>
    <input id="item2" type="checkbox"/>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <label for="item3">
      Item 3
    </label>
    <input id="item3" type="checkbox"/>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Another solution is to write JS animation, for example using "[window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame)" API, to animate height of "ul" element. (I think that this is what exacly is happening on [stripe.com](http://stripe.com))